# Problemas para la organización de los elementos en la vista show

Tags: html5, css3, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-3

Al desplegar la información en la vista `show`, cuando los usuarios no están autenticados, debería verse igual a cuando estén autenticados sin los formularios para ingresar respuestas y comentarios; pero los elementos aparecen totalmente desorganizados.

El problema se presenta después del `else`, cuando evalúa que no está autenticado, no he podido saber donde estoy cerrando mal los `div`s.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

show.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
            <h2 class="title-question"><%= @question.title %></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                <% vote = Vote.voted_by?(current_user,  @question) %>
                <% if vote %>
                      <%= link_to question_vote_path(@question, vote), remote: true, method: :delete, class: "question-upvote upvote-active" do %>
                          <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                          <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                      <% end %>
                <% else %>
                      <%= link_to question_votes_path(@question), remote: true, method: :post, class: "question-upvote" do %>
                          <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                          <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                      <% end %>
                <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                    <span> <%= markdown(@question.body) %> </span>
                    <span class="comments">
                      <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @question} %>
                    </span>
                      <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: [@question]} %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h2>(<%= @question.answers.count %>) Respuesta(s)</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% @question.answers.each do |answer|  %>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <% vote = Vote.voted_by?(current_user, answer) %>
                    <% if vote %>
                          <%= link_to question_answer_vote_path(@question, answer), remote: true, method: :delete, class: "question-upvote upvote-active" do %>
                              <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                              <span class="upvote-count"><%= answer.votes.count %></span>
                          <% end %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= link_to question_answer_votes_path(@question, answer, vote), remote: true, method: :post, class: "question-upvote" do %>
                                <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                                <span class="upvote-count"><%= answer.votes.count %></span>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                        <span> <%= markdown(answer.body) %> </span>
                        <span class="comments">
                          <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: answer} %>
                        </span>
                          <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: [answer.question, answer]} %>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <% end %> <!-- end do |answer|-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <%= render partial: "answers/form", locals: {question: @question} %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% else %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="question-upvote">
                        <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                        <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                    <span> <%= markdown(@question.body) %> </span>
                    <span class="comments">
                        <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @question} %>
                    </span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1 ">
                    <div>
                        <h2>(<%= @question.answers.count %>) Respuesta(s)</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
          <% @question.answers.each do |answer|  %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 question-upvote">
                   <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                   <span class="upvote-count"><%= answer.votes.count %></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                      <span> <%= markdown(answer.body) %> </span>
                      <span class="comments">
                        <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: answer} %>
                      </span>
                </div>
            </div>
          <% end %> <!-- end do |answer|-->
    </div><!-- end  class questions-->
  <% end %>  
</div>
```

Comment: @Gerry, el repositorio se encuentra actualizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tus `div` están bien, el problema está en la línea 91 de tu código:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 question-upvote">
```

Tienes la clase `question-upvote`, la cual no está presente en la misma sección del código (i.e. la que pone las respuestas) en el `if` (línea 39):

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
```

Quita la clase `question-upvote` del `div` en la línea 91 y tu alineación será la correcta.

---

Para no perder la flecha en los votos, debes agregar la clase `question-upvote` en otro `div` anidado, tal como se hace en las preguntas:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="question-upvote">
        <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
        <span class="upvote-count"><%= answer.votes.count %></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: La alineación quedó correcta  pero no me agrega la flecha encima de los votos, la clase question-upvote es la que permite dibujarla, como podría corregirlo.

Comment: @GarcíaHenry Necesitas agregar la clase `question-upvote` en otro `div`, tal como lo haces en las preguntas. Mira la respuesta actualizada.